# Why does pinch to zoom not work in custom crs in leaflet?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, gis, pinchzoom

I've setup a leaflet map with a custom CRS (EPSG:32633). The map generally works well, except that it freezes whenever I try to zoom the map using pinch to zoom on mobile devices.

The error occurring under pinch to zoom is "Uncaught Error: Invalid LatLng object: (NaN, NaN)".

Here's a jsfiddle that can be used to reproduce the problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/thL5bbnv/2/

Here's the code (which is also used in the jsfiddle):

```
// Defining  the projection system
L.Projection.UTM33 = {
  ZONE: 33,
  R_MINOR: 6356752.3142,
  R_MAJOR: 6378137,
  DEG_TO_RAD: Math.PI / 180,
  RAD_TO_DEG: 180 / Math.PI,

  bounds: L.bounds([-2500000, 3500000], [3045984, 9045984]),

  project: function(latlng) {
    var latRad = latlng.lat * this.DEG_TO_RAD,
      longRad = latlng.lng * this.DEG_TO_RAD,
      longOriginRad = (-183 + (6 * this.ZONE)) * this.DEG_TO_RAD,
      eccs = 1 - ((this.R_MINOR / this.R_MAJOR) * (this.R_MINOR / this.R_MAJOR)),
      k0 = 0.9996,
      eccps = eccs / (1 - eccs),
      n = this.R_MAJOR / Math.sqrt(1 - eccs * Math.sin(latRad) * Math.sin(latRad)),
      t = Math.tan(latRad) * Math.tan(latRad),
      c = eccps * Math.cos(latRad) * Math.cos(latRad),
      a = Math.cos(latRad) * (longRad - longOriginRad),
      m = this.R_MAJOR * ((1 - eccs / 4 - 3 * eccs * eccs / 64 - 5 * eccs * eccs * eccs / 256) * latRad - (3 * eccs / 8 + 3 * eccs * eccs / 32 + 45 * eccs * eccs * eccs / 1024) * Math.sin(2 * latRad) + (15 * eccs * eccs / 256 + 45 * eccs * eccs * eccs / 1024) * Math.sin(4 * latRad) - (35 * eccs * eccs * eccs / 3072) * Math.sin(6 * latRad)),
      x = k0 * n * (a + (1 - t + c) * a * a * a / 6 + (5 - 18 * t + t * t + 72 * c - 58 * eccps) * a * a * a * a * a / 120) + 500000.0,
      y = k0 * (m + n * Math.tan(latRad) * (a * a / 2 + (5 - t + 9 * c + 4 * c * c) * a * a * a * a / 24.0 + (61.0 - 58 * t + t * t + 600.0 * c - 330.0 * eccps) * a * a * a * a * a * a / 720));

    return new L.Point(x, y);
  },

  unproject: function(point) {
    var eccs = 1 - ((this.R_MINOR / this.R_MAJOR) * (this.R_MINOR / this.R_MAJOR)),
      e1 = (1 - Math.sqrt(1 - eccs)) / (1 + Math.sqrt(1 - eccs)),
      k0 = 0.9996,
      x = point.x - 500000,
      y = point.y,
      longOrigin = (this.ZONE - 1) * 6 - 180 + 3,
      eccps = (eccs) / (1 - eccs),
      m = y / k0,
      mu = m / (this.R_MAJOR * (1 - eccs / 4 - 3 * eccs * eccs / 64 - 5 * eccs * eccs * eccs / 256)),
      phi1Rad = (mu + (3 * e1 / 2 - 27 * e1 * e1 * e1 / 32) * Math.sin(2 * mu) + (21 * e1 * e1 / 16 - 55 * e1 * e1 * e1 * e1 / 32) * Math.sin(4 * mu) + (151 * e1 * e1 * e1 / 96) * Math.sin(6 * mu)),
      n1 = this.R_MAJOR / Math.sqrt(1 - eccs * Math.sin(phi1Rad) * Math.sin(phi1Rad)),
      t1 = Math.tan(phi1Rad) * Math.tan(phi1Rad),
      c1 = eccps * Math.cos(phi1Rad) * Math.cos(phi1Rad),
      r1 = this.R_MAJOR * (1 - eccs) / Math.pow(1 - eccs * Math.sin(phi1Rad) * Math.sin(phi1Rad), 1.5),
      d = x / (n1 * k0),
      lng = ((longOrigin * this.DEG_TO_RAD + ((d - (1 + 2 * t1 + c1) * d * d * d / 6 + (5 - 2 * c1 + 28 * t1 - 3 * c1 * c1 + 8 * eccps + 24 * t1 * t1) * d * d * d * d * d / 120) / Math.cos(phi1Rad))) * this.RAD_TO_DEG),
      lat = ((phi1Rad - (n1 * Math.tan(phi1Rad) / r1) * (d * d / 2 - (5 + 3 * t1 + 10 * c1 - 4 * c1 * c1 - 9 * eccps) * d * d * d * d / 24 + (61 + 90 * t1 + 298 * c1 + 45 * t1 * t1 - 252 * eccps - 3 * c1 * c1) * d * d * d * d * d * d / 720)) * this.RAD_TO_DEG);

    return new L.LatLng(lat, lng);
  }
};

// Defining the utm crs
L.CRS.EPSG32633 = L.extend({}, L.CRS.Earth, {
  code: "EPSG:32633",
  projection: L.Projection.UTM33,
  transformation: new L.Transformation(1, 2500000, -1, 9045984),
  scale: function(zoom) {
    return 1 / (21664 / Math.pow(2, zoom));
  }
});

// Creating map with the utm crs
var map = new L.map('map', {
  crs: L.CRS.EPSG32633,
  minZoom: 0,
  maxZoom: 15,
  zoomControl: true
}).on("load", function(e) {
    // Adding utm basemap
var layer = new L.TileLayer.WMS('https://opencache.statkart.no/gatekeeper/gk/gk.open', {
  layers: "topo2",
  format: "image/png",
  transparent: false,
  attribution: "© Kartverket"
});

layer.addTo(e.target);

}).setView([65.276178, 16.683775], 3);
```

UPDATE: Here's a stack trace for the error I'm getting:

```
Uncaught Error: Invalid LatLng object: (NaN, NaN)
    at o.LatLng (https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.2/dist/leaflet.js:5:14154)
    at Object.unproject (http://fiddle.jshell.net/thL5bbnv/2/show/:105:12)
    at Object.pointToLatLng (https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.2/dist/leaflet.js:5:18431)
    at e.unproject (https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.2/dist/leaflet.js:5:30126)
    at e.layerPointToLatLng (https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.2/dist/leaflet.js:5:30242)
    at e._fireDOMEvent (https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.2/dist/leaflet.js:6:3634)
    at e._handleDOMEvent (https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.2/dist/leaflet.js:6:3071)
    at HTMLDivElement.h (https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.2/dist/leaflet.js:6:11270)
    at e._simulateEvent (https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.2/dist/leaflet.js:8:31479)
    at e._onMove (https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.2/dist/leaflet.js:8:31242)o.LatLng @ leaflet.js:5unproject @ (index):105pointToLatLng @ leaflet.js:5unproject @ leaflet.js:5layerPointToLatLng @ leaflet.js:5_fireDOMEvent @ leaflet.js:6_handleDOMEvent @ leaflet.js:6h @ leaflet.js:6_simulateEvent @ leaflet.js:8_onMove @ leaflet.js:8h @ leaflet.js:6
leaflet.js:5 Uncaught Error: Invalid LatLng object: (NaN, NaN)(…)o.LatLng @ leaflet.js:5unproject @ (index):105pointToLatLng @ leaflet.js:5unproject @ leaflet.js:5layerPointToLatLng @ leaflet.js:5_fireDOMEvent @ leaflet.js:6_handleDOMEvent @ leaflet.js:6h @ leaflet.js:6_simulateEvent @ leaflet.js:8_onMove @ leaflet.js:8h @ leaflet.js:6
```

I'm trying to understand why pinch to zoom is failing, and what I can do to fix the problem. Does anyone know why pinch to zoom would result in a Invalid LatLng object: (NaN, NaN) when a custom projection is used?

Comment: Do you have a full stack trace of the error?

Answer (score 2):

OK, so I have traced the problem down to a call to `map.getScaleZoom()`:

[image: debug screenshot]

That function depends directly on the `scale` method of the map's CRS, which you have defined as

```
scale: function(zoom) {
   return 1 / (21664 / Math.pow(2, zoom));
}
```

Now, the `scale` method of the CRS must implement the **inverse** of the `zoom` method of the CRS. It says so in the [Leaflet API documentation for `L.CRS`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.2.html#crs).

You're not defining a `zoom` method in `L.CRS.EPSG32633`, but...

```
L.CRS.EPSG32633 = L.extend({}, L.CRS.Earth, {
```

...you're using `L.CRS.Earth.zoom()` instead. So if `scale(zoom(x))` is not 1 for any value of `x`, things will fail. First, a zoom level jumps from 1.01 to -19.4. Then, a `LatLng` gets a value of `1e+233`. Then your projection code takes that and starts spewing out `Infinity` and `NaN`, and everything ends up in flames.

**Fix the `scale` and `zoom` of methods of `L.CRS.EPSG32633` so they are idempotent.**

---

Regardless of the bug, I **encourage you to use [Proj4Leaflet](https://github.com/kartena/Proj4Leaflet)** instead of implementing projection code yourself. It's tested, it's maintained, and it supports all known EPSG projections and CRSs.

Comment: Many many thanks for the great explanation of how this works. I followed your suggestion and added a zoom method that is the inverse of the scale method, and now it works.